# Print page in jsp to take print on blank cheque

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, jsp

I am trying to design a print page in which values such as amount,amount in words,date will be read from server side (here jsp scriptlet).On taking print of this page on a blank cheque, the scriplet values should appear against corresponding labels.

I have written html code to adjust these values:

```
<div style="width:767.244094488px; float:left; height:71.811023622px;">
     <div style="width:151.181102362px; height:18.897637795px; float:right; margin-right:0.456692913px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; letter-spacing:13px; line-height:18.897637795px; font-size:15px;"><%=date%></div>
</div>
<div style="float:left; height:351.496062992px; width:767.244094488px;"  id="printdiv"><br>
<div style="width:width:767.244094488px; height:26.456692913px; float:left;">
     <div style="width:540.472440945px;height:26.456692913px; line-height:26.456692913px;  margin-left:56px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:15px; color:#000;">** <%=payee%> **</div>
</div><br><br>
<div style="width:width:767.244094488px; height:26.456692913px; float:left;">
     <div style="width:453.543307087px;height:26.456692913px; line-height:26.456692913px;  margin-left:76px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:15px; color:#000;"><%= amt1 %></div>
</div>
<div style="width:width:767.244094488px; height:26.456692913px; float:left;">
     <div style="width:453.543307087px;height:26.456692913px; line-height:26.456692913px;  margin-left:76px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:15px; color:#000;"><%= amt2 %></div>
</div>
<br>
<div style="width:188.976377953px;height:26.456692913px; float:left; line-height:26.456692913px;  margin-left:2px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:15px; color:#000;">
     <div style="width:143.622047244px; height:26.456692913px; line-height:26.456692913px;  margin-left:70.354330709px; letter-spacing:1px; font-size:15px; font-weight:bold;">** <%=amount%> **</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The page size is defined in css as:

```
body {
    height: 4in;
    width: 8in;
    position:absolute;
}
```

The widths defined above are calculated by manually measuring cheque dimensions in mm and then converting it to pixels.
When I take print out the values dont appear in front of corresponding labels as expected.

Comment: Instead make a PDF on the server. It will print much more consistently since HTML is not a precise tool to print. 

PS: Refomatting your html shows an extra </div>

Comment: but i dont want pdf saved anywhere it should only allow me to print... and when i tried with itext pdf i dont know what page size to specify in document constructor so that it will match cheque dimensions

Comment: So don't save it, just print it. The pdf can even invoke the print dialog itself

Comment: and what about its page size? the pdf should not contain any labels like 'RUPEES' but should hold place for them

Comment: I do not understand your question. If you create an A4 PDF with a cheque on it, it will print much better than if you try to force it in CSS on an html page

Comment: u r right but in that cheque the labels should not appear from our code rather they will be on blank checque itslef